# How to convert unsigned int(u16) into string value(char *)?

Tags: c

I need to convert u16(unsigned int -2 byte) value into string (not ascii).
How to convert unsigned int(u16) into string value(char *)?

Comment: In what language? C++?

Comment: i want to write this in C language.

Comment: If you don't want the string in ASCII, what encoding do you want the string in?

Comment: What s your problem with strings? Cannot  you use `sprintf` ?

Comment: have you tried sprintf();

Comment: sprintf(string, "%u", u16_value);

Comment: Sorry if it is silly. sprintf will only convert unsigned int to string or else it convert and print the output in single shot?

Comment: sprintf will only convert unsigned int to string. if you want to print it to stdout, use printf instead : printf("%u", u16_value);

Answer (score 10):

```
/* The max value of a uint16_t is 65k, which is 5 chars */
#ifdef  WE_REALLY_WANT_A_POINTER
char *buf = malloc (6);
#else
char buf[6];
#endif

sprintf (buf, "%u", my_uint16);

#ifdef WE_REALLY_WANT_A_POINTER
free (buf);
#endif
```

Update: If we do not want to convert the number to text, but to an actual string (for reasons that elude my perception of common sense), it can be done simply by:

```
char *str = (char *) (intptr_t) my_uint16;
```

Or, if you are after a string that is at the same address:

```
char *str = (char *) &my_uint16;
```

Update: For completeness, another way of presenting an `uint16_t` is as a series of four hexadecimal digits, requiring 4 chars. Skipping the `WE_REALLY_WANT_A_POINTER` ordeal, here's the code:

```
const char hex[] = "0123456789abcdef";
char buf[4];
buf[0] = hex[my_uint16 & f];
buf[1] = hex[(my_uint16 >> 4) & f];
buf[2] = hex[(my_uint16 >> 8) & f];
buf[3] = hex[my_uint16 >> 12];
```

Comment: This converts it to text, which isn't what the OP wants (I assume that's what OP means by *not ASCII*).

Comment: Looks like it. It's common to access the byte representation of an object (for binary serialisation etc).

Comment: Here's that included, as well.

Answer (score 3):

A `uint16_t` value only requires two `unsigned char` objects to describe it. Whether the higher byte comes first or last depends on the *endianness* of your platform:

```
// if your platform is big-endian
uint16_t value = 0x0A0B;
unsigned char buf[2];

buf[0] = (value >> 8); // 0x0A comes first
buf[1] = value;


// if your platform is little-endian
uint16_t value = 0x0A0B;
unsigned char buf[2];

buf[0] = value;
buf[1] = (value >> 8); // 0x0A comes last
```

Comment: how many chars in a uint16_t also depends on your platform (says the person who's spent the last N years working on a platform with a 16-bit char).

Comment: Only if you're working with a C99 stdint.h. There's nothing that says a non-C99 implementation can't provide a 16-bit type called uint16_t!

Comment: No you're quite right. POSIX systems do mandate `CHAR_BIT==8` and also reserve the use of type names ending in `_t`, but there's no indication that OP is using a POSIX system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf(str, "%u", a); //a is your number ,str will contain your number as string
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want to do, but it sounds to me that what you want is a simple cast.

```
uint16_t val = 0xABCD;
char* string = (char*) &val;
```

Beware that the string in general is not a 0-byte terminated C-string, so don't do anything dangerous with it.

Comment: He want to convert to to cast.

Comment: As I stated, I didn't find it clear. I think my interpretation of the question is perfectly reasonable, even though I may not have been correct.